# Tinder cards in ios-swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi all I am developing an ios app in swift.I am a newbie here.I want to develop an app in which tinder style cards effect will be there. We can do it with

```
@IBAction func SwipeRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

}
@IBAction func SwipeLeft(sender: t UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

}
```

But what I want to try is if user user starts dragging image to left/right but without releasing the image user drags back to the starting location.I dont know how to do this.Help me in this issue.

Comment: Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer instead of a UISwipeGestureRecognizer. On each update, update the location of the card. When the gesture ends, decide whether the card will complete the swipe or not based on its location.